# How to configure network connection IP and DNS with script

Tags: windows, networking, bash

Once a week I work from a specific location where I need to plug in my cable and configure connection to be connected to internet. Here are steps that you have to do: [image]
You have to enter specific IP and DNS that are given by provider.
Is there a way to use bash script to configure it automatically?

Comment: You can do this with `netsh`, though that is not bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following commands are to be ran in administrator command prompt.

- To change IP, the command syntax is::

`netsh interface ip set address "interface name" "dhcp/static" "IPv4 address" "IPv4 mask" "gateway IPv4 address"`

Let say, my local IP 10.0.0.5, gateway 10.0.0.1, subnet mask 255.0.0.0, the command will be::

`netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet" static 10.0.0.5 255.0.0.0 10.0.0.1`

- To change DNS, the command syntax is::

`netsh int ipv4 add dnsserver "interface name" "DNS IPv4 address" "index=integer" "yes/no"`

Let say, my DNS servers will be 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220, the command will be::

`netsh int ipv4 add dnsserver "Ethernet" address=208.67.222.222 index=1
 netsh int ipv4 add dnsserver "Ethernet" address=208.67.220.220 index=2`

Comment: Bonus points for a command to revert everything back to DHCP.

Comment: and how to revert to automatic DHCP?

Comment: Do not set that static IP address and use DHCP instead of that static option.

Comment: To reset dns
netsh interface ip set dns "Ethernet" dhcp

Answer (score -1):

You can try the steps below:

1. Click on the Windows Key on your Keyboard and Press X. On the
   menu that appears click control panel.
2. In Category view click on Network and Internet
3. Click on Network and Sharing Center
4. Click on Change Adapter Settings
5. Right click on Local Area Connection and click Properties
6. Click Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IP) then click Properties
7. Change ‘Dot’ to Use the following IP address and input your IP and DNS information.
8. Click OK to save and apply your settings.

Comment: The OP asked how to do this with a script.